# cURL succeeded using command line but got 504 Gateway Timeout using php curl_exec?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I tried to fetch some data using php `curl_setopt` in my code. But it went through 2 minutes of loading, then got 504 Gateway Timeout error. Here's the code:

```
function sendRequest($url, $data, $token = '') {
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36");

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Strangely, I succeeded fetching the data instantly using command line cURL with the same options:

```
curl --url "http://x.x.x.x" --header "Connection: keep-alive" --http1.1 --verbose --request "POST" -d "data1=value1" -d "data2=value2" --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"
```

The server that hosts the code and the destination is in the same network and firewall is not activated in both servers. What could be the cause of the failure?

Comment: What is purpose of `"Connection: keep-alive"` if both `curl` and `curl_close` in libcurl happen immediately after requests are done?

Comment: @273K To be honest, I'm not sure, I'm new to this cURL procedure. I just copy some code from somewhere to my code and not really putting much attention to each option. Is it makes more sense to just keep "Connection: close" since I close the request with `curl_close` in the end? Or do you suspect it has something to do with my failure to fetch data?

Comment: You don't need setting any header. Using a copied code not understanding how it works is very bad idea, even harmful. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

No clue what `$data` is. If it's an associative array, try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```